# Find the probability that two samples contain all different balls.

Tags: probability

> Suppose we have a box containing $n$ balls numbered $1, 2,\dotsc,n$. A random sample of size $k$ is drawn without replacement and the numbers on the balls noted. These balls are than returned to the box and a second random sample of size $r$ is then drawn without replacement. $(r + k < n)$ Find the probability that two samples contain all different balls.

---

This was my approach.
Take the $k$ balls first.
Then the probability that of not getting the same $k$ balls again is $$1-\frac{1}{(n)(n-1)(n-2)\dotsm(n-k)}$$
I hope that makes sense.
In this I ignored the second sample size, I don't think that matters. 
Is it right?

Comment: The second sample size does matter since each extra ball in the second sample reduces the probability that there is no overlap between the two samples

Answer (score 1):

The probability is $$\ _{(n-k)}C_r\over  \ _nC_r$$  choosing $r$ balls from $(n-k)$ [favourable cases] divided by choosing $r$ balls from $n$ [sample space].